# Laravel - belongsToMany with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created 3 Database Tables:

**users**
 - id
 - username
 - ...

**messages**
 - id
 - title
 - message

**messages_user**
 - messages_id
 - user_id
 - receive_user_id

The fields in **messages_user** are set as foreign key to the according tables.

The function I want to archieve is:
I want to get all messages of a user, be it the one he created himself or he just received.

Current status:
I am able to get all messages a user created by using a inside my User-Model:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Messages', 'messages_user');
```

My problem currently is that I'm not able to get the received messages as well with one query. I could start a second query, but I'm sure their is a way to archieve that in another way.

Is that possible and if, how? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

Model users.php

```
class Users extends Model    {
   // Relation with messages_user table
      public function messages_user() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Messages_user','id');
      }
}
```

Model messages.php

```
class Messages extends Model    {
   // Relation with messages_user table
      public function messages_user() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Messages_user','id');
      }
}
```

Model messages_user.php

```
 class Messages_user extends Model    {
   // Relation with users table
      public function send_user() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Users','user_id');
      }

      public function receive_user() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Users','receive_user_id');
      }
     // Relation with messages table
      public function messages() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Messages','messages_id');
      }

}
```

In controller

```
   public function user_all_messages($id) {
      $data = Messages_user::with('send_user')
          ->with('receive_user')
          ->where('user_id', $id)
          ->orWhere('receive_user_id', $id)
          ->get();
   }
```

Comment: Holy moly, that's exactly what I wanted to know! I needed to add the missing Model (messages_user) and rename my relation table to "messages_users". Big thanks for your help, I will try to use what I learned from you to my following functions. :)

Comment: edit: The only thing missing now is the message itself. I will try to get the hang of it and will update this post when successfully completed. :)

Comment: Marked the message as the solution. I just had to add `->with('messages')` to the query. :)